# if a linear group of dimension $\geq 2$ has a dense one-parameter subgroup , then it is isomorphic to Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

if a linear group of dimension $\geq 2$  has a dense one-parameter subgroup , then it is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{T^n }$

I think it is enough to show $\mathbb{T }$ $\times$  $\mathbb{R }$ can not have dense one-parameter subgroup i try to solve it with basic topological and group theoritic facts but i cannot do it.Do i need to use analysis or something else ?

Comment: I can read two questions from this: a) Is it enough to show $\Bbb T\times \Bbb R$ does not have a dense one-parameter subgroup? b) How can I show that $\Bbb T\times \Bbb R$ does not have a dense one-parameter subgroup? Which do do need answered?

Comment: Well i think if we solve the last one it will imply first one but if you have an idea please talk about both of them

Comment: Well, the scond is quite easy: The group homomorphism $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb T\times \Bbb R$ followed by the projection onto the second factor $\Bbb R$ must either be identically $0$ or an isomorphism. In the first case, $f(\Bbb R)$ is not dense because it stays away from any point $(t,1)$, in the second case, it stays away from any $(t,1)$ except the one point actually in $f(\Bbb R)$

Comment: You first need to define "linear" group, which is very unclear.